# Last image on JLabel is shown for all after adding JLayeredPane in loop

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

Sorry for the bad title, could not think of anything better.

I am building a card game.

The below method takes a Card object as argument and returns me a JLayeredPane with a JLabel having the image for the card.

```
private JLayeredPane getCardPane(Card card) {
    JLayeredPane cardPane = new JLayeredPane();

    GridBagLayout gblCardPane = new GridBagLayout();
    cardPane.setLayout(gblCardPane);

    cardImageIcon = card.getImageIcon();

    JLabel lblCard = new JLabel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(cardImageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    };

    GridBagConstraints gbcLblCard = new GridBagConstraints();
    cardPane.add(lblCard,gbcLblCard);

    return cardPane;
}
```

I have a section like below adding all cards in my hand to another JLayeredPane jlpMyCards:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hand.getCardCount(); i++) {
    JLayeredPane thisCard = getCardPane(hand.getCard(i));

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,thisCard);

    jlpMyCards.add(thisCard);
}
```

and finally add the jlpMyCards to the frame.

**On the rendered frame I see all cards in hand (as per count) but all cards are displaying the last image that is loaded.** - ***WHY?***

I tried printing the cards with

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,thisCard);
```

The popup dialog is showing the correct images.

NOTE: I guess the below method from Card class might also create the issue.

```
public ImageIcon getImageIcon() {
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource(
                    getValueAsString().toLowerCase() + "_of_"+ 
                    getSuitAsString().toLowerCase() + ".png").toURI()));
        //Rescaling Image
        Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(100, 146, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        return new ImageIcon(dimg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: `ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getResource(
                    getValueAsString().toLowerCase() + "_of_"+ 
                    getSuitAsString().toLowerCase() + ".png").toURI()));` would better be `ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(
                    getValueAsString().toLowerCase() + "_of_"+ 
                    getSuitAsString().toLowerCase() + ".png"));` since by time of deployment this image will probably be part of a Jar, and therefore accessible by URL only.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I was not aware of MCVE. I will put the problem in MCVE ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Did the changes as you suggested in the 2nd comment.

Comment: At a guess, your `for` loop is blocking the EDT; see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Why are you painting the icon instead of setting the JLabel's icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering all suggestions I changed the `card.getImageIcon()`. Instead I am now using `getCardImagePane()` which returns a JLayeredPane after setting the image to it.

Below is the code I am using now:

```
public CardImagePane getCardImagePane(boolean small) {
    return new CardImagePane(this.getClass().getResource(
            getValueAsString().toLowerCase() + "_of_"
                    + getSuitAsString().toLowerCase() + ".png"), small);
}

class CardImagePane extends JLayeredPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6829613165978637891L;

    private Image image;

    public CardImagePane(URL imgURL, boolean small) {
        Image tempImg = new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage();
        this.image = tempImg.getScaledInstance(Constants.CARD_WIDTH,
                Constants.CARD_HEIGHT, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        Dimension size = new Dimension(small ? Constants.CARD_WIDTH_SMALL
                : Constants.CARD_WIDTH, Constants.CARD_HEIGHT);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Thanks to all. Do tell me if something better could be done.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration of the loop you assign value to field `cardImageIcon`. And when rendering all labels calls `getImage()` (in their `paintComponent` method) on the same `cardImageIcon` object (which was set during last iteration).

Instead of keeping it as a field, you can keep it as a local variable:

```
final ImageIcom cardImageIcon = card.getImageIcon();

JLabel lblCard = new JLabel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(cardImageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
```

It is important to declare it as final to use it in `paintComponent` method.

**OR**

perhaps you can just use `JLabel` constructor that takes `Icon` as an argument in constructor:

```
JLabel lblCard = new JLabel(card.getImageIcon());
```

Comment: I guess I should try to do some thing without overriding the `paintComponent` method. What do you suggest?

Comment: You can convert `cardImageIcon` to local variable. I'`ve updated the answear.

Comment: `g.drawImage(cardImageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);` would best be `g.drawImage(cardImageIcon.getImage(), 0, 0, this);` since every `JComponent` **is an** `ImageObserver` ..

Comment: or you can just use JLabel constructor that takes Icon as an argument in constructor